# OpenCv Accessing pixels

Tags: opencv, pixel

```
for (x=0; x<width-1; x++){
    for(y=0; y<height-1; y++){
        s = cvGet2D(binImage, x, y);
        printf("%f\n", s.val[(x,y)]);
        //if (s.val[(x,y)] == 0){

        //} 
    }
}
```

I just wanna ask about this piece of code here. I am printing the pixel values in each iteration but it doesn't print completely and I get segmentation fault in the end of the program run. What must be the cause of this and how can I fix this code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
s = cvGet2D(binImage, x, y);
```

should be

```
s = cvGet2D(binImage, y, x);
```

Although, the documentation is not very clear on this...

Also, I think to print out the pixel you just want to do this (assuming a single channel float image):

```
printf("%f\n", s.val[0]);
```

Comment: I'm really just starting to learn OpenCV so may I just ask why the printed values are always 255.000000 after I followed your instructions? From the code, I wanted to identify if the pixel is black or white. How can I possibly do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: 255 is generally considered white for an 8-bit image (i.e., all bits are set). Black is therefore the opposite 0 (i.e., all bits are unset).

Comment: did this work for you cmsl?  had the same problem and was getting out of bounds exceptions.  I was able to guess that the cvGet2D function takes (y,x) and not (x,y), but then all of the pixel values returned are (255, 0 , 0 , 0) which is bogus (not the case).

Comment: see my question if you are interested:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764785/out-of-range-error-when-accessing-2d-pixel-values-in-opencv-using-get2d