# Out of range error or wrong returned values when accessing 2d pixel values in OpenCV using Get2D

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, python-imaging-library

This is a simple program that uses OpenCV (in Python) to import an image, convert it to grayscale and display it in a window.  Then, when the user clicks a position in the window, a flood-fill is performed from that point.  In addition, **when the user clicks the point, the program should print the original 2D pixel value at that position.**

Unfortunately when too far to the right, OpenCV gives me an out of range error, although it works for most parts of the image.  The flood fill itself is working properly at all x-y positions in the image.

In working regions the output looks like this:

```
mouse at: 70 , 84
Image Size (220, 186)
cv2: (183.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
pil im: 255
```

But then when I go too far to the right, the output looks like this:

```
mouse at: 198 , 129
Image Size (220, 186)
OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (index is out of range) in cvGet2D
print "cv2: " +   str(cv2.cv.Get2D(cv2.cv.fromarray(gray), x, y));
cv2.error: index is out of range
```

I tried converting the image to a PIL Image and use the Image.getpixel((x,y)) function, which worked in the sense that it didn't give me an out of range exception, but it unfortunately returns 255 at all x-y points (which is not the case).

I tried switching the position of the x-y parameters in the OpenCV function call str(cv2.cv.Get2D(cv2.cv.fromarray(gray), x, y)) to str(cv2.cv.Get2D(cv2.cv.fromarray(gray), y, x)), and this got rid of the out of range error, but results in a spurious return of (255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) at all positions.  Indeed, the tipping-point for this error, >186 in the x dimension, does happen to be the length of the y dimension.  This is a major clue but does not solve the problem (my test image size is 220 x 186 as you can see above).

```
import cv2
import cv
import PIL.Image
import numpy

def main():

#mouse event handler flag
CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN = 1;

#THE CODE AT ISSUE IS CONTAINED IN THIS MOUSEHANDLE FUNCTION
def mouseHandle(event, x, y, flag, param):
    if (flag == 1):
        print "mouse is at: " + str(x) + " , " + str(y);
        pilim = Image.fromstring("L", cv.GetSize(cv2.cv.fromarray(gray)),cv2.cv.fromarray(gray).tostring())
        print "Image Size " + str(cv.GetSize(cv.fromarray(gray)))
        print "cv2: " +   str(cv2.cv.Get2D(cv2.cv.fromarray(gray), x, y));
        print "pil im: " + str(pilim.getpixel((x,y)))
        cv2.floodFill(gray,mask,(x,y), (255,255,0),diff,diff)
        cv2.imshow('flood fill',gray)


#THE CODE BELOW IS BASIC OPENCV STUFF TO LOAD THE IMAGE AND INITIATE MOUSECALLS
#reads in the image
im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

#converts it to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('grayscale', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0);

# flood fill variables
diff = (6,6,6)
mask = zeros((h+2,w+2),uint8)


# show the result in an OpenCV window, calling setMouseCallBack on mouse click
cv2.imshow('flood fill',gray)
cv2.setMouseCallback('flood fill', mouseHandle, CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: test image]
[image: test image after flood fills (working)]

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve the problem.

**Firstly, regarding the out of bounds exception.**  As it turns out cv.Get2D takes pixel coordinates in y,x form, which can be confusing.  Using the line cv.Get2D(cv2.cv.fromarray(gray), y, x)); solved the out of bounds issue.

**Secondly, regarding the spurious pixel values.**  This one was really dumb, sorry guys.  For some reason the CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN flag causes the mouseHandle function to execute twice.  I thought I was seeing the entire output each time I clicked, but was actually seeing the *second* output after the flood fill had occurred, which explains the values of 255 at all positions.  Sad but true!

At first I suspected that I was somehow not using cv.fromarray properly, since cv2.imread('image.jpg') returns type 'numpy.ndarray', and cv.LoadImage('image.jpg') returns type 'cv2.cv.iplimage'. I tried loading my image using OpenCV1's cv.LoadImage('image.jpg') and using cv.FloodFill(im2, (x,y), (255,255,0), diff, diff, 0, cv.fromarray(mask)) for the flood filling (note the changes in parameter order from OpenCV 1 vs 2), and printing the x-y coordinates using cv.Get2D(cv2.cv.fromarray(gray), y, x));  But the problem remained.  And, lo and behold, the answer was much simpler :)

**I did notice something interesting and bizarre when I was debugging though.**  As I mentioned, I tried to do the flood filling with OpenCV 1 and OpenCV2, but depending on which flood fill I called first in the mouseHandle function, only that one executed!

Below is an output (after mouseclick) with the order:

```
cv2.floodFill(gray,mask,(x,y), (255,255,0),diff,diff)
cv.FloodFill(im2, (x,y), (255,255,0), diff, diff, 0, cv.fromarray(mask))
```

output:

```
mouse at: 202 , 13
(220, 186)
cv2: (35.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
cv1: (35.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
pil image: 35
mouse at: 202 , 13
(220, 186)
cv2: (255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
cv1: (35.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
pil image: 255
```

Below is another output (after mouseclick) with the order:

```
cv.FloodFill(im2, (x,y), (255,255,0), diff, diff, 0, cv.fromarray(mask))
cv2.floodFill(gray,mask,(x,y), (255,255,0),diff,diff)
```

output:

```
mouse at: 137 , 126
(220, 186)
cv2: (146.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
cv1: (146.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
pil image: 146
mouse at: 137 , 126
(220, 186)
cv2: (146.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
cv1: (255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
pil image: 146
```

The order of those two lines of code is the only change I made!  Note that the pil image string output follows what the cv2 floodfill is doing trivially because it contains the same data.